# aggregation with group by, inner join and nested conditions in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, join, group-by, aggregate

First of all I am sorry if this is a basic question, I am new to queries in MongoDB. Well, what I need is to find the latest registers for a `worker` in my `WorkerLocationContext` document and the latest register for each `sensor` in my `HeatMeasureContext` document, then join it by their `location` and then apply some filters. Here are my Schemas:

`HeatMeasureContext`:

```
const heatMeasureContextSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
    sensor: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'MeasureSensor', required: true },
    humid: { type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true },
    globe: { type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true },
    mercury: { type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true },
    internal: { type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true },
    external: { type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true }
}, { timestamps: true })
```

`MeasureSensor`:

```
const measureSensorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: false },
    type: { type: String, required: false, uppercase: true,
        enumValues: ['MEASURE'], default: 'MEASURE' },
    location: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Location' },
    sensorType: { type: String, required: false, uppercase: true,
        enumValues: ['WORKER_ATTACHED', 'ENVIRONMENT'], default: 'ENVIRONMENT' },
    measurerType: { type: String, required: false, uppercase: true,
        enumValues: ['HEAT', 'RUID'] },
    placementType: { type: String, required: false, uppercase: true,
        enumValues: ['INTERNAL', 'EXTERNAL'], default: 'INTERNAL' }
})
```

`WorkerLocationContext`:

```
const workerLocationContextSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
    sensor: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'LocationSensor', required: true },
    worker: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Worker', required: true }
}, { timestamps: true })
```

`Location`

```
const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: false },
    type: { type: String, required: false, uppercase: true,
    enumValues: ['REST', 'ROOM', 'COURTYARD'], default: 'ROOM' }
})
```

`Worker`

```
const workerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    workGroup: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'WorkGroup', required: false }
})
```

I have built my query like this:

```
WorkerLocationContext.aggregate([ 
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "HeatMeasureContext",
            "localField": "sensor.location._id",
            "foreignField": "sensor.location._id",
            "as": "HMContext"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "$and": [
                { "$or": [
                    { "$and": [ 
                        { 
                            "HMContext.sensor.placementType": { "$eq": "INTERNAL" }}, 
                            {"HMContext.internal": { "$gte": limit} 
                        },
                        { 
                            "HMContext.sensor.placementType": { "$eq": "EXTERNAL" }}, 
                            {"HMContext.external": { "$gte": limit} 
                        },
                    ]},
                ]},
                { "WorkerLocationContext.worker.location.type": { "$ne": "REST" } }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "null",
            "workers": {
              "$count": {}
            },
            "hmDatetime": {
                "$max": "$HMContext.createdAt"
            },
            "wlDatetime": {
                "$max": "$WorkerLocationContext.createdAt"
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Basically, my goal with it is to count how many workers fit in that condition according to their current location, thus the latest registers in the context tables. I have tried some simulations in the [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/), but nothing succeeded. Is it possible to be done in MongoDB? Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to use MongoDB, which is a document store, for what seems to be a perfectly relational schema?

Comment: Hi @mustaccio, it is because I am using a MEAN Stack for my application, just because of it... you mean that it is not possible with mongo?

Comment: I don't know Mongo well enough to tell you what's possible, it just doesn't look like the right tool for the job.

Comment: @mustaccio thanks for the input, unfortunately it would give me a lot of work to change the database now :(

Comment: Might be a lot of work to do this (and every task like this) when  you could just write a 10 line query in SQL and be done with it.